# I am trying to update loss_dt in bacclaim table to trans_dt from other table bactrans on claim_id where loss_Dt >trans_dt

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, correlated-subquery

I am setting loss_dt to trans_dt where `loss_Dt >trans_Dt`. `loss_Dt` is in `bacclaim` and `trans_Dt` is in `bactrans` both have `claimid` common

```sql
UPDATE bacclaim t1
   SET (t1.loss_dt) = (SELECT  t2.trans_dt
                         FROM bactrans t2
                        WHERE t1.claim > t2.claim)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM bactrans t2
     WHERE t1.claim = t2.claim and t1.loss_dt>t2.trans_dt );
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: DDL statements for your tables; DML statements for some sample data; and your expected output. Also, is there always at most a one-to-one mapping between `claimid` in bacclaim` and in`bactrans` or can there be multiple rows in `bactrans` that match a row in `bacclaim`?

Answer (score 0):

A `MERGE` statement might be what you are looking for:

```sql
MERGE INTO bacclaim dst
USING bactrans src
ON ( src.claimid = dst.claimid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET loss_td = src.trans_dt
  WHERE src.loss_td > dst.trans_dt
```